# Convert duration to number of seconds in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following time duration strings in Excel:

```
0 Seconds
0 Seconds
2 Days 12 Minutes
10 Days 4 Hours 38 Minutes
9 Hours 3 minutes
0 Seconds
```

Is it possible to convert this into the number of seconds per row using a generic formula in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Parse the string and use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSE(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),((ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,INT((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))/2)+1))-1)*2+1)*999,999)),{"Seconds","Minutes","Hours","Days"},0),1,60,60*60,60*60*24)*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),((ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,INT((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))/2)+1))-1)*2)*999+1,999)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason i do not get the same results as you in cell B3-B5. Any idea why?

[link](https://prnt.sc/q2fmes)

Comment: Not without seeing the actual data(not a picture).  This is very dependent on there only being 1 space between the all the parts.  So not sure, best is to try and use The evaluate formula on the formula tab and see where it is going wrong.  as you can see in the photo I am getting the correct answer.